# how to prevent accessing web page using history in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have a web application ... using URL in browser history anyone can able to access the page. Is there any way to disable accesssing page from history or typing the url in address bar?

For example ,  staffs and managers using this website. some pages are only accessible by managers. but using url in history staff also accessing this page.

My question is "Is there any way to clear the history in asp.net?"

Comment: Typing a URL in the address bar is the same as requesting that page. How would you access a "web" page if it's not by requesting it via HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i understand your question, if you want your page should not open directly by Url then you can do it by this way

```
Uri u = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (u != null)
            return true;
        else
        {
            //Here user try to hit your Page url directly
            //Then you can redirect that user to your default Page or Home Page
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question right, you dont want to someone to access your page from browser history or by typing it in the address bar? The answer is no, you cannot restrict it like that unfortunately. A bit more context would be helpful

Comment: Thanks Senthil Natarajan... Is there any other way to secure my page?

Comment: There are lot of ways to secure your page, you can setup profiles (asp membership) to restrict access to certain pages. You can restrict by IP Address as well

Comment: yes added login. my code is just checking session variable has login id or not, then allow to access the page. So i thought to check roles also. but have more pages.. have to check role in each page. So in master page , I'm checking previous URL. So if user access from history or type url in address bar it redirects to error page.